# string encryption/decryption

Tags: excel, vba, string, encryption

I am interested if it's possible to do string encryption/decryption using Excel Visual Basic and some cryptographic service provider.

I have found a walk-through [Encrypting and Decrypting Strings in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx), but it seems it's valid for standalone Visual Basic only.

So would you suggest me another encryption method or show how the walk-through could be adopted for Excel Visual Basic?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The link you provide shows how to perform string encryption and decryption using VB.NET, and thus, using the .NET Framework.

Currently, Microsoft Office products cannot yet use the [Visual Studio Tools for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Applications) component which will enable Office products to access the .NET framework's BCL (base class libraries) which, in turn, access the underlying Windows CSP (cryptographic server provider) and provide a nice wrapper around those encryption/decryption functions.

For the time being, Office products are stuck with the old VBA ([Visual Basic for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)) which is based on the old VB6 (and earlier) versions of visual Basic which are based upon COM, rather than the .NET Framework.

Because of all of this, you will either need to call out to the Win32 API to access the CSP functions, or you will have to "roll-your-own" encryption method in pure VB6/VBA code, although this is likely to be less secure.  It all depends upon how "secure" you'd like your encryption to be.

If you want to "roll-your-own" basic string encryption/decryption routine, take a look at these link to get you started:

[Encrypt a String Easily](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5676)
<strike>[Better XOR Encryption with a readable string](http://www.codetoad.com/visual_basic_better_xor.asp)</strike>

[vb6 - encryption function](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=334313)
<strike>[Visual Basic 6 / VBA String Encryption/Decryption Function](http://paste2.org/p/435362)</strike>

If you want to access the Win32 API and use the underlying Windows CSP (a much more secure option), see these links for detailed information on how to achieve this:

<strike>[How to encrypt a string in Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821762)</strike>

[Access to CryptEncrypt (CryptoAPI/WinAPI) functions in VBA](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/84d49593-2d8e-4e7c-af3a-61882af9557d)

That last link is likely the one you'll want and includes a complete VBA Class module to "wrap" the Windows CSP functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very detailed explanation and some useful links. Wish all answers here were like yours.

Comment: Several dead links above :-(

Answer (score 7):

**This code works well for me (3DES Encryption/Decryption):**

I store INITIALIZATION_VECTOR and TRIPLE_DES_KEY as environment variables (obviously different values than those posted here) and get them using VBA Environ() function, so all sensitive data (passwords) in VBA code is encrypted.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const INITIALIZATION_VECTOR = "zlrs$5kd"  'Always 8 characters

Public Const TRIPLE_DES_KEY = ">tlF8adk=35K{dsa" 'Always 16 characters

Sub TestEncrypt()
    MsgBox "This is an encrypted string: -> " & EncryptStringTripleDES("This is an encrypted string:")
    Debug.Print EncryptStringTripleDES("This is an encrypted string:")
End Sub

Sub TestDecrypt()
    MsgBox "u99CVItCGiMQEVYHf8+S22QbJ5CPQGDXuS5n1jvEIgU= -> " & DecryptStringTripleDES("u99CVItCGiMQEVYHf8+S22QbJ5CPQGDXuS5n1jvEIgU=")
End Sub


Function EncryptStringTripleDES(plain_string As String) As Variant

    Dim encryption_object As Object
    Dim plain_byte_data() As Byte
    Dim encrypted_byte_data() As Byte
    Dim encrypted_base64_string As String

    EncryptStringTripleDES = Null

    On Error GoTo FunctionError

    plain_byte_data = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding").GetBytes_4(plain_string)

    Set encryption_object = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider")
    encryption_object.Padding = 3
    encryption_object.key = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding").GetBytes_4(TRIPLE_DES_KEY)
    encryption_object.IV = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding").GetBytes_4(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR)
    encrypted_byte_data = _
            encryption_object.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(plain_byte_data, 0, UBound(plain_byte_data) + 1)

    encrypted_base64_string = BytesToBase64(encrypted_byte_data)

    EncryptStringTripleDES = encrypted_base64_string

    Exit Function

FunctionError:

    MsgBox "TripleDES encryption failed"

End Function

Function DecryptStringTripleDES(encrypted_string As String) As Variant

    Dim encryption_object As Object
    Dim encrypted_byte_data() As Byte
    Dim plain_byte_data() As Byte
    Dim plain_string As String

    DecryptStringTripleDES = Null

    On Error GoTo FunctionError

    encrypted_byte_data = Base64toBytes(encrypted_string)

    Set encryption_object = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider")
    encryption_object.Padding = 3
    encryption_object.key = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding").GetBytes_4(TRIPLE_DES_KEY)
    encryption_object.IV = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding").GetBytes_4(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR)
    plain_byte_data = encryption_object.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encrypted_byte_data, 0, UBound(encrypted_byte_data) + 1)

    plain_string = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding").GetString(plain_byte_data)

    DecryptStringTripleDES = plain_string

    Exit Function

FunctionError:

    MsgBox "TripleDES decryption failed"

End Function


Function BytesToBase64(varBytes() As Byte) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = varBytes
        BytesToBase64 = Replace(.Text, vbLf, "")
    End With
End Function


Function Base64toBytes(varStr As String) As Byte()
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("b64")
         .DataType = "bin.base64"
         .Text = varStr
         Base64toBytes = .nodeTypedValue
    End With
End Function
```

Source code taken from here: https://gist.github.com/motoraku/97ad730891e59159d86c

Note the difference between the original code and my code, that is additional option **encryption_object.Padding = 3** which forces VBA to **not** perform padding. With padding option set to 3 I get result exactly as in C++ implementation of DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt algorithm and which is in agreement with what is produced by this [online tool](http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/).

Comment: what if i have to increase the IV size to 16 and set cipher mode as CBC?

Answer (score 7):

### This code works fine in VBA and can easily be moved to VB.NET

Avoids dealing with not "normal" characters. You decide in AllowedChars what characters to allow.

```
Public Function CleanEncryptSTR(MyString As String, MyPassword As String, Encrypt As Boolean) As String
'Encrypts strings chars contained in Allowedchars
'MyString = String to decrypt
'MyPassword = Password
'Encrypt True: Encrypy   False: Decrypt
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ASCToAdd As Integer
    Dim ThisChar As String
    Dim ThisASC As Integer
    Dim NewASC As Integer
    Dim MyStringEncrypted As String
    Dim AllowedChars As String

    AllowedChars = "&0123456789;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    If Len(MyPassword) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(MyString)
'            ThisASC = Asc(Mid(MyString, i, 1))
'            ThisASC = IntFromArray(Asc(Mid(MyString, i, 1)), MyVector())

            ThisChar = Mid(MyString, i, 1)
            ThisASC = InStr(AllowedChars, ThisChar)

            If ThisASC > 0 Then
                ASCToAdd = Asc(Mid(MyPassword, i Mod Len(MyPassword) + 1, 1))
                If Encrypt Then
                    NewASC = ThisASC + ASCToAdd
                Else
                    NewASC = ThisASC - ASCToAdd
                End If
                NewASC = NewASC Mod Len(AllowedChars)
                If NewASC <= 0 Then
                    NewASC = NewASC + Len(AllowedChars)
                End If

                MyStringEncrypted = MyStringEncrypted & Mid(AllowedChars, NewASC, 1)
            Else
                MyStringEncrypted = MyStringEncrypted & ThisChar
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        MyStringEncrypted = MyString
    End If

    CleanEncryptSTR = MyStringEncrypted

End Function
```

Comment: This is working well on Mac OS excel, but doesn't seem to want to work on Windows for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Create a Class Module called clsCifrado:

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Binary

Private clsClave As String

Property Get Clave() As String
    Clave = clsClave
End Property

Property Let Clave(value As String)
    clsClave = value
End Property


Function Cifrar(Frase As String) As String

    Dim Cachos() As Byte
    Dim LaClave() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Largo As Integer

    If Frase <> "" Then
        Cachos() = StrConv(Frase, vbFromUnicode)
        LaClave() = StrConv(clsClave, vbFromUnicode)
        Largo = Len(clsClave)

        For i = LBound(Cachos) To UBound(Cachos)
            Cachos(i) = (Cachos(i) Xor LaClave(i Mod Largo)) + 34
        Next i

        Cifrar = StrConv(Cachos(), vbUnicode)
    Else
        Cifrar = ""
    End If

End Function

Function Descifrar(Frase As String) As String

    Dim Cachos() As Byte
    Dim LaClave() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Largo As Integer

    If Frase <> "" Then
        Cachos() = StrConv(Frase, vbFromUnicode)
        LaClave() = StrConv(clsClave, vbFromUnicode)
        Largo = Len(clsClave)

        For i = LBound(Cachos) To UBound(Cachos)
            Cachos(i) = Cachos(i) - 34
            Cachos(i) = (Cachos(i) Xor LaClave(i Mod Largo))
        Next i

        Descifrar = StrConv(Cachos(), vbUnicode)
    Else
        Descifrar = ""
    End If

End Function
```

---

Now you can use it in your code:

to cipher

---

```
Private Sub btnCifrar_Click()

    Dim Texto As String
    Dim cCifrado As clsCifrado

    Set cCifrado = New clsCifrado

    '---poner la contraseña
    If tbxClave.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "The Password is missing"
        End Sub
    Else
        cCifrado.Clave = tbxClave.Text
    End If

    '---Sacar los datos
    Texto = tbxFrase.Text

    '---cifrar el texto
    Texto = cCifrado.Cifrar(Texto)

    tbxFrase.Text = Texto

 End Sub
```

---

To descipher

---

```
Private Sub btnDescifrar_Click()

    Dim Texto As String
    Dim cCifrado As clsCifrado

    Set cCifrado = New clsCifrado

    '---poner la contraseña
    If tbxClave.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "The Password is missing"
        End Sub
    Else
        cCifrado.Clave = tbxClave.Text
    End If

    '---Sacar los datos
    Texto = tbxFrase.Text

    '---cifrar el texto
    Texto = cCifrado.Descifrar(Texto)

    tbxFrase.Text = Texto
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic symmetric encryption/decryption example:

```
Sub testit()
    Dim inputStr As String
    inputStr = "Hello world!"

    Dim encrypted As String, decrypted As String
    encrypted = scramble(inputStr)
    decrypted = scramble(encrypted)
    Debug.Print encrypted
    Debug.Print decrypted
End Sub


Function stringToByteArray(str As String) As Variant
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = str
    stringToByteArray = bytes
End Function

Function byteArrayToString(bytes() As Byte) As String
    Dim str As String
    str = bytes
    byteArrayToString = str
End Function


Function scramble(str As String) As String
    Const SECRET_PASSWORD As String = "K*4HD%f#nwS%sdf032#gfl!HLKN*pq7"

    Dim stringBytes() As Byte, passwordBytes() As Byte
    stringBytes = stringToByteArray(str)
    passwordBytes = stringToByteArray(SECRET_PASSWORD)

    Dim upperLim As Long
    upperLim = UBound(stringBytes)
    ReDim scrambledBytes(0 To upperLim) As Byte
    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = LBound(stringBytes) To upperLim
        scrambledBytes(idx) = stringBytes(idx) Xor passwordBytes(idx)
    Next idx
    scramble = byteArrayToString(scrambledBytes)
End Function
```

Be aware that this will crash if your given input string is longer than the SECRET_PASSWORD. This is just an example to get started with.

Comment: There's a typo in `Dim enctrypted As String` should be `Dim encrypted As String`

Answer (score 2):

You can call pipe excel cell data through any shell script.
Install the GPL Bert (http://bert-toolkit.com/) R language interface for Excel.
Use the R script below in Excel to pipe cell data to Bash / perl / gpg / openssl.

```
 c:\> cat c:\R322\callable_from_excel.R
    CRYPTIT <- function( PLAINTEXT, MASTER_PASS ) {
    system(
      sprintf("bash -c 'echo '%s' |
        gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo blowfish --force-mdc --passphrase '%s' -q  |
        base64 -w 0'",
        PLAINTEXT, MASTER_PASS),
      intern=TRUE)
  }

DECRYPTIT <- function( CRYPTTEXT, MASTER_PASS ) {
    system(
      sprintf("bash -c 'echo '%s'|
        base64 -d |
        gpg --passphrase '%s' -q |
        putclip | getclip' ",CRYPTTEXT,MASTER_PASS),
      intern=TRUE)  
  }
```

In Excel, you can try: C1=CRYPTIT(A1,A2) and C2=DECRYPTIT(C1,A2)
Optional: putclip saves decrypted text in clipboard.
Both functions types are: String -> String.
Usual caveats about escaping single-quotes in single-quoted strings.