# Login form with username and password from worksheet list

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, userform

I am trying to do a login form validating the password and username from sheet "users". It works when the username and password are correct.

When username or password are not correct (not a match to list on sheet "users") I want label8 to print "insert username and Password" and not give access to userform1.

```vb
Private Sub LoginBTT_Click()

Application.Visible = False

Dim temp As String

Pw = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.TextBox1.Value, Worksheets("users").Range("a2:b6"), 2, 0)

If TextBox2.Value = Pw Then
    Me.Hide: Application.Visible = False
    Unload Me
    UserForm1.Show
Else
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    Label5.Visible = True
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    Label7.Visible = True
    Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
    Label8 = "Wrong Username or Password"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that it's dead easy for anyone to get a list of the passwords that you have stored in that sheet. Even if you hide it. If your goal is secure authentication, then this is NOT the way to go.

Comment: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: @teylyn, Can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

i create userform and named it uf_Login with properties: showmodal=true, specialefect=2
in this userform i create 2 textboxes named tb_Login and tb_Password and 2 command buttons named cb_login and cb_exit. In tb_Password properites define password char =* ( u can place any char u want). Both command buttons have tabstop properties turned to false

in thisworkbook object paste code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    uf_Login.Show
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

in userform code paste

```
Private Sub cb_Exit_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Private Sub cb_Login_Click()
    Dim str_Wanted As String, str_Password As String
    Dim rng_FindWanted As Range
    
    str_Wanted = Me.tb_Login
    Set rng_FindWanted = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("users").Cells.Find(str_Wanted)
    If rng_FindWanted Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Wrong LOGIN!!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
        Me.tb_Login = ""
        Me.tb_Password = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If  '   If rng_FindWanted Is Nothing
    str_Password = Me.tb_Password
    If str_Password <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("users").Cells(rng_FindWanted.Row, 2).Text Then
        MsgBox "Wrong PASSWORD!!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
        Me.tb_Login = ""
        Me.tb_Password = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If  '   If str_Password <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("users").Cells(rng_FindWanted.Row, 2)
    Unload Me
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub tb_Login_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        Me.tb_Password.SetFocus
    End If  '   If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn
End Sub

Private Sub tb_Password_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        Call cb_Login_Click
    End If  '   If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    HideTitleBar.HideTitleBar Me
End Sub
```

To hide title bar of userform paste this code in standard module named HideTitleBar

```
'PLACE IN A STANDARD MODULE
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Public Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                       Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                       ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowLong _
                       Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                       ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                       ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
                       Lib "user32" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function FindWindowA _
                       Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                       ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Sub HideTitleBar(frm As Object)
    Dim lngWindow As Long
    Dim lFrmHdl As Long
    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    Call SetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)
End Sub
```

hope will help.

Comment: but i think u shouldnt save passwords and logins in sheet.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.
What would be a good procedure to save the passwords in your opinion please?

Comment: encryption is best method. read this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470939/string-encryption-decryption

Comment: if enryption is to hard you can try place logins and passwords in board in code by declarate board when userform initialize or workbook is open.

Comment: thank you so much. Will try to learn new approach advised